# Clojure, Codox: How to Use :doc metadata instead of docstring?

Tags: clojure

I am looking into [codox](https://github.com/weavejester/codox).  I know that docstrings are parsed and displayed, but is it possible for me to enable `^{:doc "Description"}` to be parsed?  For example, this works

```
(defn get-foo "Get the Foo" [] @foo)
```

but not this

```
(defn get-foo ^{:doc "Get the Foo"} [] @foo)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented [here](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/defn), defn will accept an "attr" map which can contain documentation via the `:doc` keyword. So this would work.

```
user> (defn get-foo {:doc "Get the foo"} [foo] @foo)
#'user/get-foo
user> (meta get-foo)
{:doc "Get the foo"}
```

However you have used the `^` reader macro to add the first following form (the map) as metadata not to the symbol `get-foo`, but to the second following form, your argument vector. The defn and def macros do not inspect the argument vectors for metadata, and so your apparent docstring is ignored.

```
user> ^{:doc "foo"} []
[]
user> (meta ^{:doc "foo"} [])
{:doc "foo"}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not where the ^:doc annotation goes. It goes before the function name, because you're trying to attach metadata to the symbol that is the function's name. This is unrelated to codox, but is a general thing about clojure metadata and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the caret. What you want is to pass an attribute map in that place, not metadata. This should work:

```
(defn get-foo {:doc "Get the foo"} [foo] @foo)
```